# Javascript innerHTML change url function not working in IE only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I’m a fairly novice web programmer so apologies if my code is not as well polished as it should be. My website works fine in Chrome, Safari and Opera but not in Internet Explorer.

I use a javascript function that changes the source of innerhtml to navigate in my site.  For some reason, in Internet Explorer only, the second time the innerhtml is changed using a navigation click, nothing happens. If I clear the cache on the blank screen the correct innerhtml source loads.

The relevant code as follow:

HTML:

```
<div  id="BannerImage">
  <div  id="BannerImageSmall">
        <iframe   width="700" height="230" border="0" frameborder="0"     scrolling="no" src="movies/classic_fades/_classic_fades.html" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function linkClicking(myLink)
     {
         var dv = document.getElementById('BannerImage');

         //remove all child nodes
        while (dv.hasChildNodes()) {
        dv.removeChild(dv.lastChild);

        }    
    dv.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../images/banners/homeBright.jpg")';

         dv.innerHTML='<object  data="' + myLink + '" style = "height:340px; width:730px; clear:both; overflow: hidden; width: 100%;"></object>';

     }

</script>
```

CSS:

```
#BannerImage
    {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-color: #000000;
        background-image: url('../images/banners/home.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        min-height: 370px;
        height: auto; !important
        border-top: 25px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
        width: 800px;
        margin: auto
        float: right;
        margin-left: 100px;
        clear: both;        
    }
```

Comment: Any error messages? Why remove all child nodes if you're replacing the innerHTML anyway? Try it without that `while` loop.

Comment: no error messages at all

Comment: Removing the while loop stops the javascript from changing the content in all browsers

Comment: Works for me without the loop: http://jsfiddle.net/m6sfpv2j/